# How many similar diagonal matrices are there

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $D$ be a diagonal $5 \times 5$ matrix (base field is $R$), such that the diagonal entries $\delta_{ii}, 1 \le i \le 5$ are all distinct. How many diagonal matrices are there which are similar to $D$? I am not sure what results I can use for showing the solution of this, nor am I sure what the actual solution is although I am inclined to assume it is something to do with permutations of the diagonal.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Over **what field**?

Comment: @DonAntonio apologies, the field is $R$

Comment: Similar matrices will have the same eigenvalues. How may ways can you permute the eigenvalues?

Comment: Then for any five  different *fixed* values of $\;\Bbb R\;$, there will be as many similar matrix to the given as permutations on 5 objects there are...

Comment: ok so just 5! ? thanks for the help